# Python 3: setup.py: pip install that does everything (build_ext + install)

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I'm learning how to use `distutils`, and there's something I don't understand, and I wish someone could explain this to me.

I already am successful in creating tar.gz packages that can be installed with

```
pip install mypackage.tar.gz
```

I did this with `setup.py`, with a simple script that runs the function `setuptools.setup()`, which I call using `python3 setup.py sdist`.

**What I wanna learn now:** How to include building extensions in this.

**My problem:** I couldn't find any comprehensive text that explains how a `pip install` of a package that has a `build_ext` class can get it to build, then install.

If we look at [this example](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/e44258991eda05b32c3e63ad0bea409fe6aca1a2/setup.py), for the famous tool `cx_freeze` package, we see:

- There's an inherited `build_ext` class
- There's a method `build_extension()`
- in `setup()`, the variable `cmdclass`, which contains a dict that contains the class `build_ext`

My question: What gets `cx_freeze` to build the extension and then install it? Is having a `cmdclass` defined with `build_ext` enough to achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After many tests, I learned that this is related to how `pip` works, not how `setup.py` works. It turns out that after writing your `setup.py` file and using `pip` to install, this is what happens:

1. pip creates a temporary file, in Linux it's in `/tmp`, and on Windows it's in the temp dir of the user.
2. pip downloads/extracts the package to that temp directory (whether from a tar.gz or from an online source or from a repository)
3. pip runs the following operations in order:

   - `setup.py install`
   - `setup.py build`
   - `setup.py install_lib`
   - `setup.py build_py`
   - `setup.py build_ext`

And all this depends on whether you have stuff defined in the `cmdclass` parameter of `setup()`. For example, `build_ext` will run only if you have `build_ext` defined in `cmdclass` AND you have `ext_modules` defined in the parameters of your `setup()` call. So `ext_modules`, for example, is expected to be a list of `Extension()`, which contains all the information about every extension. The function in the class `build_extension(self,ext)` will be executed on every element of that list.

All these classes that go to `cmdclass` (I use `build` and `build_py`) have a method called `run()` that you should override to put in your custom building procedure.

After all that is done, pip *installs* (or copies) the `packages` defined in `setup()` (which are basically directories in that temp) to your Python directory, which is the end of the installation, and deletes temp files.

There's more details to all this, but I guess this is good for a starter. I saw none of this explained anywhere comprehensively. So I hope this helps and saves people the empirical testing I had to do to learn this.

Comment: Many years later, same problem about the lack of documentation / clear information about how to create Python packages with extension modules that require a non-trivial build process. Thank you for taking the time to share this!