# Install TA-LIB with clang compiler error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, clang, clang++, ta-lib

### Setup

Using an ubuntu20 t2.micro on AWS

```
sudo apt-get install python3 clang # Make sure gcc is not used instead of clang
```

**Install the TA-LIB C library.**

```js
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar zxvf
cd ta-lib
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

**Install pip, python3-dev, python3.9-dev, and the python TA-LIB wrapper**

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo CC=clang python3.9 get-pip.py 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3.9-dev
sudo CC=clang python3.9 -m pip install TA-LIB
```

---

### Errors

I receive this error output from the last command

```js
$ CC=clang python3.9 -m pip install TA-LIB
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting TA-LIB
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.24.tar.gz (269 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from TA-LIB) (1.22.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-LIB
  Building wheel for TA-LIB (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ay3k6nzj
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/
  Complete output (61 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_polars.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  running build_ext
  building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o
  In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:689:
  In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:5:
  In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
  In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1960:
  /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
  #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
   ^
  talib/_ta_lib.c:38706:103: warning: passing 'TA_FuncInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_FuncInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_FuncInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_FuncInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetFuncInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:211:48: note: passing argument to parameter 'funcInfo' here
                             const TA_FuncInfo **funcInfo );
                                                 ^
  talib/_ta_lib.c:38977:126: warning: passing 'TA_InputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_InputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_InputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_InputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetInputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:442:68: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                       const TA_InputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                     ^
  talib/_ta_lib.c:39227:129: warning: passing 'TA_OptInputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_OptInputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_OptInputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_OptInputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetOptInputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:446:74: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                          const TA_OptInputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                           ^
  talib/_ta_lib.c:39473:127: warning: passing 'TA_OutputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_OutputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_OutputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_OutputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetOutputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:450:70: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                        const TA_OutputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                       ^
  talib/_ta_lib.c:40072:125: warning: passing 'TA_FuncHandle **' (aka 'unsigned int **') to parameter of type 'const TA_FuncHandle **' (aka 'const unsigned int **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib__ta_check_success(__pyx_n_s_TA_GetFuncHandle, TA_GetFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name, (&__pyx_v_handle)), 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(1, 751, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:155:52: note: passing argument to parameter 'handle' here
                               const TA_FuncHandle **handle );
                                                     ^
  6 warnings generated.
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/opt/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/homebrew/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/lib -lta_lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-LIB
  Running setup.py clean for TA-LIB
Failed to build TA-LIB
Installing collected packages: TA-LIB
    Running setup.py install for TA-LIB ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3qtsugx0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/.local/include/python3.9/TA-LIB
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_polars.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o
    In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:689:
    In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:5:
    In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
    In file included from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1960:
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
     ^
    talib/_ta_lib.c:38706:103: warning: passing 'TA_FuncInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_FuncInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_FuncInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_FuncInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetFuncInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:211:48: note: passing argument to parameter 'funcInfo' here
                               const TA_FuncInfo **funcInfo );
                                                   ^
    talib/_ta_lib.c:38977:126: warning: passing 'TA_InputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_InputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_InputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_InputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetInputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:442:68: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                         const TA_InputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                       ^
    talib/_ta_lib.c:39227:129: warning: passing 'TA_OptInputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_OptInputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_OptInputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_OptInputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetOptInputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:446:74: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                            const TA_OptInputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                             ^
    talib/_ta_lib.c:39473:127: warning: passing 'TA_OutputParameterInfo **' (aka 'struct TA_OutputParameterInfo **') to parameter of type 'const TA_OutputParameterInfo **' (aka 'const struct TA_OutputParameterInfo **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_v_retCode = TA_GetOutputParameterInfo(__pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib___ta_getFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name), __pyx_v_idx, (&__pyx_v_info));
                                                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:450:70: note: passing argument to parameter 'info' here
                                          const TA_OutputParameterInfo **info );
                                                                         ^
    talib/_ta_lib.c:40072:125: warning: passing 'TA_FuncHandle **' (aka 'unsigned int **') to parameter of type 'const TA_FuncHandle **' (aka 'const unsigned int **') discards qualifiers in nested pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_5talib_7_ta_lib__ta_check_success(__pyx_n_s_TA_GetFuncHandle, TA_GetFuncHandle(__pyx_v_function_name, (&__pyx_v_handle)), 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(1, 751, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/ta-lib/ta_abstract.h:155:52: note: passing argument to parameter 'handle' here
                                 const TA_FuncHandle **handle );
                                                       ^
    6 warnings generated.
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/opt/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/homebrew/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-R/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/lib -lta_lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-btb1_xuf/ta-lib_0aa6c802ac734a0dbb58621b44b06499/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3qtsugx0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/.local/include/python3.9/TA-LIB Check the logs for full command output.
```

The most important line from that looks like

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

When I run `clang++ -v` I get

```
$ clang++ -v
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

---

### Attempted solutions

I have installed already tried installing these packages to try and fix it:
`python3-clang-9`, `autoconf`, `libtool`, `pkg-config`

installing `build-essential` is not an option because it installs `gcc` and I am trying to use `clang` instead of `gcc`

Comment: What if  `alias x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc="clang"`?

Comment: Try to set `CC=clang` _before_  running ta-lib's `./configure`.

Comment: Does the `make` command return an error when installing the TA-LIB C library?

Comment: It seems that the problem is isolated to AWS. I was trying to reproduce all steps, that @Sam did and TA-LIB installed correctly under Ubuntu 20.04 (VirtualBox) using clang compiler.

Comment: @Domarm, Are you positive that it is not `gcc` what gets called?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% positive. Running `sudo CC=clang python3.9 -m pip install TA-LIB --no-cache-dir --verbose` Gives me output `clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/talib/_ta_lib.o`

Comment: Doing the same without `sudo CC=clang` gives error: `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed: No such file or directory`. Same as for @Sam. So pip was trying to use gcc.

Comment: Did `LDSHARED` fix it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the variable `CC` is insufficient- you also need to set `LDSHARED` as well. Your pip install command should look like:

```sh
sudo CC=clang LDSHARED=clang python3.9 -m pip install TA-LIB
```

Or perhaps:

```sh
sudo LDSHARED="clang -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions" \
CC="clang -pthread" python3.9 -m pip install TA-LIB
```

EDIT:

To elaborate, when you're pip installing TA-LIB, its going to do a number of things, [including fetching/extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629156/6221024), and then runs `setup.py` with some options:

- `setup.py install`
- `setup.py build`
- `setup.py install_lib`
- `setup.py build_py`
- `setup.py build_ext`

We care about the last one, `setup.py build_ext`. This is going to run logic contained within [distutils.build_ext](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py), particularly it constructs a compiler object and customizes it:

```py
from distutils.sysconfig import customize_compiler, get_python_version

class build_ext(Command):
    def run(self):
        ...

        self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
                                     verbose=self.verbose,
                                     dry_run=self.dry_run,
                                     force=self.force)
        customize_compiler(self.compiler)
```

If we peek inside [distutils.sysconfig](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py), and look at `customize_compiler()`, we'll see where checks for some environment variables, and configures the compiler object accordingly:

```py
if 'CC' in os.environ:
    newcc = os.environ['CC']
    if (sys.platform == 'darwin'
            and 'LDSHARED' not in os.environ
            and ldshared.startswith(cc)):
        # On OS X, if CC is overridden, use that as the default
        #       command for LDSHARED as well
        ldshared = newcc + ldshared[len(cc):]
    cc = newcc
if 'CXX' in os.environ:
    cxx = os.environ['CXX']
if 'LDSHARED' in os.environ:
    ldshared = os.environ['LDSHARED']
if 'CPP' in os.environ:
    cpp = os.environ['CPP']
else:
    cpp = cc + " -E"           # not always
if 'LDFLAGS' in os.environ:
    ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['LDFLAGS']
if 'CFLAGS' in os.environ:
    cflags = cflags + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
    ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
if 'CPPFLAGS' in os.environ:
    cpp = cpp + ' ' + os.environ['CPPFLAGS']
    cflags = cflags + ' ' + os.environ['CPPFLAGS']
    ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['CPPFLAGS']
if 'AR' in os.environ:
    ar = os.environ['AR']
if 'ARFLAGS' in os.environ:
    archiver = ar + ' ' + os.environ['ARFLAGS']
else:
    archiver = ar + ' ' + ar_flags

cc_cmd = cc + ' ' + cflags
compiler.set_executables(
    preprocessor=cpp,
    compiler=cc_cmd,
    compiler_so=cc_cmd + ' ' + ccshared,
    compiler_cxx=cxx,
    linker_so=ldshared,
    linker_exe=cc,
    archiver=archiver)
```

Particularly, we see it setting  `ldshared`, and passing this along to the compiler as `linker_so` (and set as an attribute within).

In the [distutils.unixcompiler.UnixCCompiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/distutils/unixccompiler.py) (the subclass of CCompiler used here, returned by `new_compiler()` earlier), we find an implementation of `link()`, using this executable, and then spawning it as a process:

```py
if target_desc == CCompiler.EXECUTABLE:
    linker = self.linker_exe[:]
else:
    linker = self.linker_so[:]
...

self.spawn(linker + ld_args)
```

We'll also find the default values of the compiler/linker/etc.

```
executables = {'preprocessor' : None,
           'compiler'     : ["cc"],
           'compiler_so'  : ["cc"],
           'compiler_cxx' : ["cc"],
           'linker_so'    : ["cc", "-shared"],
           'linker_exe'   : ["cc"],
           'archiver'     : ["ar", "-cr"],
           'ranlib'       : None,
          }
```

On your system, `cc` is just a symlink to `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`, so until we provided the override for the linker explicitly in an environment variable, this is where it was getting that value from.

Comment: `LDSHARED="clang -shared"` worked, can you give some explanation around the 2 methods you listed

Comment: @Sam updated with details

Comment: @Sam if there's any other clarifications need me to make, please let me know as soon as possible, so I still have time to make changes before your bounty expires (13hr).

Comment: Otherwise, if the answer is satisfactory, could you award the bounty? (StackOverflow will not automatically award it, it will just vanish and nobody gets the rep)

Comment: There’s a 24 hour grace period

Comment: @sam, ah- you have plenty of time then. I did not know know of the grace period, thank you.